# XNA Framework based game doesn't install

Tags: windows-7, gaming, xna

I'm trying to run [this XNA based game](http://gamejolt.com/games/platformer/void-rogue/12988/), but clicking on the executable has no result at all (error messages, dialog boxes, etc).

I have installed the XNA Frawemork. I'm trying to run it on my Win 7 32 bits laptop. I'm able to run it on my girlfriend's 32 bits Win 7 laptop.

Comment: Did you install the XNA framework?

Comment: @techie007 From the game page: "If you do not have XNA installed, download the game, run Setup.exe, and the setup will install all required files for you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my video card is not good enough to run the game:

There are a few instances of Event ID 1026 on the Event Log, all of them including the line "**Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException.**"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to use the XNA web installer which is out of date/offline.

Try installing the full version of the XNA framework from MS: [Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=20914)

Comment: I downloaded the full package, upon installing it I found it was already present, chose the "repair" option, it finished with no errors, but the issue persists.